# Problem with proper cuDNN instalation for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried making small models with tensorflow, CPU worked for me. But when the training time got substantial, I wanted to switch to GPU-based training. I installed CUDA v11.2, along with cuDNN (v8.1.0, for CUDA v11.2). I did everything as in the official tutorial from the Tensorflow website. So, I tried testing if I detect my GPU (3070Ti) with this code:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

the output says, that I'm missing some DLLs.

```
2023-11-26 21:29:39.945054: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:39.945347: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-11-26 21:29:42.183093: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.183551: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.183990: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.184408: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.184918: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.185301: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.185662: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2023-11-26 21:29:42.185969: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
```

Even though they are installed, the path variable is set to the exact location where they are.

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\lib
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\extras\CUPTI\include
C:\Users\----\Documents\cuda\include
C:\Users\----\Documents\cuda\bin
```

I tried reinstalling the TensorFlow library, both Tensorflow, and Tensorflow-gpu.
I installed the TensorFlow in the version that supports both CUDA and cuDNN (v2.10.0)
I reinstalled both CUDA and cuDNN.
I tried almost all of the solutions posted here, but no results.

Comment: Could you double check that the filenames match exactly, including the number? As well as what exact version of CUDA is requested by the tensorflow version you have installed? It's likely that cuda toolkit 11.2 (which is installed) has files named cudart_112.dll and similar, not 110 (and they consequently may not be compatible either)

Comment: What OS are you on? Did you insert the cuda path in your PATH variable?

Comment: The file names in the cuda folder are the same as the ones that TensorFlow requests. To double check, i copied the names from the error message into the file explorer search field and it found those files. I use Windows 11. Both, the cuda and cudnn directories are added to PATH variable.